# Strange window bar on Ubuntu 22.04 (Qt)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu

When I create a new Qt project on Qt Creator and start building and running it, the result window has a strange title bar like this:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

I'm using Qt 6.5.2 (I don't know does this happen when use different version of Qt)

How do I make my window bar on Ubuntu like that?

**Interesting part**

The Qt packages that I'm stuck with is installed by Qt Installer Binaries.

If I install Qt with the standard Ubuntu packages (`sudo apt install qt6-base-dev`) and start building the project with them. The window bar is showed as I want.

Comment: Are you programming, building and running inside of WSL? Or other virtual machine running on Windows? Or is it a standalone Ubuntu system, without any virtual machines, containers or emulation?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu natively on my machine, no VM or emulation.

Comment: Then are you using the standard Ubuntu development packages for Qt? Or have you installed Qt yourself, perhaps built from source? I_ wonder because if you use the default Ubuntu packages, it should use the theme configuration of your system. But if you build and install Qt yourself, in a non-standard location, it might use its own default theme settings.

Comment: The Qt packages that I'm using were installed by Qt Installer Binaries for Linux.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you! you resolved 50% my problem, see the updated question for more :)